# No connection when booting

Tags: boot, wireless

I installed Ubuntu and now I have a dual boot system with Windows 7. I use wireless using an Intellinet Wireless 150N USB Mini Adaptor Model 524773. It has given me trouble free connection for the past 5 years using Windows 7 and still does. However when I reboot the system and boot into Ubuntu with the adaptor plugged in, Ubuntu does not recognize it and the wifi does not connect. The LED inside the adapter does not flash.

Unplugging and plugging the adapter back make the LED inside the adapter flash and wifi starts normally.

But my question is that why Ubuntu does not detect the adapter during boot?

Comment: Can you edit your question to have the output of `lsusb` in it both before and after you plug it in? Can you also provide what happens if you boot with out the adapter pluged in and then plug it in on ubuntu Does it work.

Comment: Not sure what is being asked. With adapter installed during reboot Ubuntu does not detect it. After reboot adapter is installed Ubuntu detects it and there is wifi connection. Why is Ubuntu not detecting it during a boot?

Comment: Like to delete this post and repost it again since I have not had any responses. Can this be done?